# how to stop Double Click on my aspx page on server side without Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, button, double-click

I am facing automatic multiple clicks on my Button in all pages of my website. I put JavaScript to disable the button on click. It's working but on the server side it's not working. I want to stop double click on server side without JavaScript.

Comment: There aren't any out of the box solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to be easily done without JavaScript included.  But let's assume there is no way to use JavaScript for a reason.

You will need to trace the server side calls, for example: 
You can have a seconds life time variable (session variable) and each time you call the server you set it to true, and if you found it true on the next call this means it is a second click.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code to the button

```
btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit, null) + ";");
```

Please let me know if this solved your problem

Comment: on localhost its working button work with single click but on sever its not working what can i do

Answer (score 0):

In your click event you can just add in

```
Btnsubmit.enabled=false
```